# Show as it is date from moment irrespective of time zone

Tags: javascript, angular, moment-timezone

I did console logging for moment object and its showing following results :
[image: console log of moment object]

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "/Date(1616070600000+0530)/", _isUTC: true, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}
_d: Thu Mar 18 2021 18:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
```

I want to show on UI is `Thu Mar 18 2021 18:00:00` irrespective of user location and his/her current time zone.

I tried something like this

```
console.log(moment.utc(this.response_d));
    this.res_d = moment.utc(this.response_d).utcOffset('+5:30').format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss A');
```

and in html file as :

```
<div class="ItemBox QuantityGrid MiniGrid responseDate">
       Response due date :     
        {{ res_d }}  
    </div>
```

but it shows `Response due date : 2021-03-18 12:30:00 PM`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have anough details about your response_data_string how it is got in your TypeScript controller..
 But I recommand you to use [angular date pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) instead of using moment instance inside your html template.
But if you want , did you tried to force formatting your moment instance like this :

```
{{ moment(response_date_string,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').toDate()|date  }}
```

if this is not working, you can debug your **response_date_string** variable by using `{{response_date_string|json}}`

Comment: in my response_date_string I am getting 616090400000 and i need to show date with time which should be in this case 2021-03-18 18:00:00

Comment: @rahularyansharma by testing your **comment timestamp** and your **edited post timestamp** the two times are differents, where **1616070600000** is equal to **18-03-2021 13:30** and where **616090400000** is equal to **10-07-1989 18:13**. first step: you have to fix wether your values is correct from your Backend. Second step: to format a timestamp to the correct format that you **mentioned before** in your post, you can use this formatting process `moment(yourTimeStamp).format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss')` without using `|date` because **.format(..)** will return a string not a date instance.

Comment: also, you can replay your process in this link too by [Jssfiddle using momentJs](http://jsfiddle.net/7uwnsgpv/), take a look

Comment: thanks , but when i run the following var now = moment(1616070600000).format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss');

console.log(now); its "Thu Mar 18 2021 18:00:00" which is correct but in your case its 18-03-2021 13:30 . may be you are in different time zone then me thats why this difference but i want a solution where irrespecitve of user location or time zone its should always show "Thu Mar 18 2021 18:00:00"

Comment: I think the best way is to make your dates standardized is to use **UTC** date forme instead of local zone. Moment JS offers a lot of functionalities to parse UTC, but the little difficult thing is to use the same in your backend to make things relative.